# Struggling with memory management and create array method

Tags: iphone, ios4, memory-management, memory-leaks, methods

I'm struggling to find the correct way to release an array after my method has been called. I wonder if there is a better way to achieve what I'm trying to acheive with my method:

```
- (NSArray *) setupDetailArray : (NSString *) selectedCategory {

    // Load .plist file
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];

    // Load .plist into a new dictionary
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    // Drill down to next level
    NSArray *faceSelection = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:detailTitle]];
    [dict release], dict = nil;

    // Set up link to App Delegate
    UltimateRageAppDelegate *dataCenter = (UltimateRageAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    dataCenter.faces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Set app delegate faces to array
    dataCenter.faces = faceSelection;
    [dataCenter.faces release];

    return faceSelection;

    // [faceSelection release], faceSelection = nil; ?????? 

}
```

And I call my method in viewDidLoad

```
// If faceArray is empty, create it
if (faceArray == nil)
    faceArray = [self setupDetailArray:detailTitle];
...
```

My application is leaking memory here, and I'm really looking for a way to release everything once I'm done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should return an autoreleased array which is then retained by the method that calls it if it wants/needs to keep it.

```
- (NSArray *) setupDetailArray : (NSString *) selectedCategory {
...
// Create the array, but don't own it
NSArray *faceSelection = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:detailTitle]] autorelease];
...
return facesSelected;
}
```

Now the code that calls this method should retain the object if it needs it.  So, in your viewDidLoad

```
if (faceArray == nil)
    faceArray = [[self setupDetailArray:detailTitle] retain];
...
```

If faceArray is an instance variable in your class, then you can just release it in your dealloc method.

You are also leaking memory here

```
// Set up link to App Delegate
    UltimateRageAppDelegate *dataCenter = (UltimateRageAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    dataCenter.faces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

    // Set app delegate faces to array
    dataCenter.faces = faceSelection;  
    [dataCenter.faces release];
```

This should be

```
// Set up link to App Delegate
    UltimateRageAppDelegate *dataCenter = (UltimateRageAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    dataCenter.faces = faceSelection;
```

I'd suggest you read (and re-read and re-read) the docs on memory management and read up on properties, setters and the dot notation.

[Apple Objective-C Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1)

Comment: Ok I will. I struggle with that doc as I'm completely new. I trust one day it will make sense!

Comment: You just need to read it over and over again and try to find as many examples as you can.  Eventually it makes sense!

Comment: OK - i read the memory management docs, and I've sorted out a couple of leaks, but one remains. I've used your code, but could you help me figure out why:

Answer (score 1):

```
dataCenter.faces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You allocate a non-autoreleased array and assign it to the property `faces` (I bet it has the `retain` modifier).

```
dataCenter.faces = faceSelection;
```

Now you assign as new array to the `faces` property, but you haven't properly release the previous NSMutableArray.

```
[dataCenter.faces release];
```

You now indirectly release your `faceSelection` array.

You leak at least one NSMutableArray every time you run that method. You should do it like this instead:

```
// Drill down to next level
NSArray *faceSelection = [[dict objectForKey:detailTitle] copy];
[dict release], dict = nil;

// Set up link to App Delegate
UltimateRageAppDelegate *dataCenter = (UltimateRageAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

// Set app delegate faces to array
dataCenter.faces = faceSelection;

return [faceSelection autorelease];
```

Your method should return an autoreleased object. The only methods that should return retained objects are methods whose name:

- starts with `alloc`
- starts with `new`
- contains `copy`

All other methods should return autoreleased objects.

Comment: Interesting - nice to know how things should be done - i.e. all methods should return autorelease except in certain situations. I have an issue though, as when I come to reuse this code, by going back up to the master view, and clicking another row, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to set dataCenter.faces = faceSelection;

Answer (score 1):

Other way for doing this.

```
//Declare method as follows. 
- (void) setupDetailArray : (NSString *) selectedCategory arrFaceArray:(NSArray *)faceArray
{
}
```

And I call my method in viewDidLoad

```
if (!faceArray)
{
    faceArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]; //Alloc in ViewDidLoad and release in ViewDidUnload or dealloc.
    faceArray = [self setupDetailArray:detailTitle arrFaceArray:faceArray]; 
}
```

Also consider the @DarkDust answer for maintaining autoreleased objects. Both are the possible ways.

Comment: I don't quite understand this answer. How is the void method returning the array object?

Comment: @squarefrog you are passing reference here so no need to return any array and you will add items to that array which is passed as reference. Gotcha ?